# Qt3D ExtrudedTextMesh is not a type

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt3d

I tested this code in Qt 5.9.1 for mac, and qtcreator reports error: ExtrudedTextMesh is not a type.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Extras 2.0


// 3D 文本示例
Entity{
    components: [
        // bug: ExtrudedTextMesh is not a type, Qt 5.9.1 mac
        ExtrudedTextMesh {
            text: "Hello 3D"
            depth: 0.2
        },
        PhongAlphaMaterial{
            id: colorMaterial
            ambient: Qt.rgba( 1, 0, 0, 1.0 )
            diffuse: Qt.rgba( 1, 0, 0, 1.0 )
            specular: Qt.rgba(1, 0, 0, 1.0 )
            shininess: 1.0
            alpha: 0.5
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @eyllanesc,  I can only see the answer because I am above 10k rep.  Please un-delete your answer and I will upvote it.  In case he doesn't undelete it, his answer was to do `import Qt3D.Extras 2.9`  as it is new in Qt 5.9.  The docs have a bug as of 5.10.1 and the bug may be found [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61451)

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been reported, review it [QTBUG-61451](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61451). In the comments says:

> Use import Qt3D.Extras 2.9 as it's new in Qt 5.9.

I have tried it and it works.

Comment: Worked for me!  Thanks @eyllanesc!